# With Pokki installed to show a "Start Button" in Windows 8, how do I temporarily switch to the Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8

The Windows key now brings up the Pokki window, which I like. I don't want to change the configuration for that.

However, sometimes albeit rarely, I want to see the Modern UI. Is there some secret key combination or hotspot to temporarily get the Windows 8 Modern UI to be visible without changing what the Windows button does?

Comment: Yep, hovering over the right half of the screen does bring up the charms menu. So, at least using the mouse you can get back to the Modern UI from there...

Comment: I don't use Pokki you can try this.  Hover in the very bottom corner of the screen.  If a charm menu appears the "Start Screen" icon should be visible.

Comment: Ahh great, a -1 for a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Press Windows Key+C to bring up the charms menu.
2. Click the "Start" icon on the charms menu to get the Modern UI Start
   screen.

Comment: Thank you! That does work and I've given your answer an up-vote for the time being. I can't believe that they've made it this difficult to access the Modern UI, though. I was hoping that there would be a single-key combination that could get me there, like the Windows key used to.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn - actually they didn't make it that hard. You modified the default behavior because of a third-party program. You could normally get to it by pressing a single button.  I mean you can't attack something for being "difficult" when the only reason its "difficult" is because you modified the default behavior of the operating system

Comment: @Ramhound, yes but as good as Pokki is, I'm surprised that there is no single Windows-??? key combination shortcut to get you back to the modern UI.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn - There is....Its the "Windows Key" but you changed the default behavior.  Attempting to explain that your problem is with Pokki not Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound, my point is that if Pokki changed the Windows key to access the Pokki start menu pop-up, they also should have added a "Windows and some other key" shortcut to get the old behavior. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn - Yes they should...Except its a start screen repacement ;-)